# open-cv findChessboardCorners fails to detect corners

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, corner-detection

This is the image (24 inner-corners from left to right and 15 from top to bottom):
[image]

This is the code:

```
img = cv2.imread('path to image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
val = cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (24, 15), val)
```

The code for another (very similar image but with more space on the left hand side) seems to work fine:
[image]

I fail to understand what the issue is (I am using python 3.8.8 with open-cv 4.5.3)?

Comment: The top image does not have the brown border at the top, so finding the white edge may not work. Put a brown border of at least one pixel at the top and bottom and try again. See cv2.copyMakeBorder()

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried a boarder (all around) with a thickness of 100 but it still won't work.